# getting error " NameError (uninitialized constant Quiz::Quizmodules" for module name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have code like below.

```
model/quiz.rb
class quiz
  include Quizmodule

  def self.a
     module_methode(a,b)
  end
end

lib/quizmodule.rb
module Quizmodule
  def module_methode(a,b)
     render(jason: {quiz: a})
  end
end
```

When i try to access module method in model method. It gives me this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Quiz::Quizmodule
```

help me to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Class can not be `include`d. What you can include is module.

```
module Quizmodule # <======== not class
  def module_methode(a,b)
     render(jason: {quiz: a})
  end
end
```

Since it was a typo, and you did not try to include a class, move your module from `lib` to `models/concern`.

P.S. Your code has number of issues, it is non-conventional and will not work as you "intend".

1. `class quiz` - class name should start with capital letter
2. `def self.a; module_methode(a,b); end` - it will fail with `undefined method module_methode for class:quiz` (to overcome it you will want to `extend Quizmodule`)
3. `module_methode(a,b)` in `self.a` - you're using `a` and `b`, but never pass them to `a` method (though these might come from some other class level methods or whatever)
4. in `Quizmodule#module_methode` you're passing in two arguments but are using only one.

Comment: ohh.. i update question. class to module. but still error is there

Comment: @pm as you see, the errors says `Quizmodules` note **`s`** at the end. Most likely it's just a typo. But there is no module called `Quizmodules`

Comment: i change and try that too. :(

Comment: @P_M move your module from `lib` to `models/concern`

Comment: why this is negetive vote ? on this answer it is more clear and to the point on the answer +up

Comment: @RajarshiDas yea, it is often to see a valid answer downvoted on SO :)